# How to change an http script to https

Tags: html, http, https

In my code I have the following tag:

```
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js" integrity="...."></script>
```

I have to change its format to `https` instead of using `http`. However, when I add in the s and change it to `https://...`, here's the error:

```
Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' atttribute for resource'https://cdnjs..." with computer SHA-256 integrity '...' The resource has been blocked.
```

Comment: have you tried using `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js`, this will allow the browser to use the appropriate protocol, you won't need to think which protocol to use? Also, the problem might have to do with the SSL certificate of the resource you're accessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a right integrity key for https version. CDNs use integrity keys for security and the integrity key must match the version of the file you're trying to load. You should get the right script tag from the site where you got the cdn link from.
Looks like what you need is:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-Ff5AdoHz3vQThC2scsjxohVP7viZvTzrYjJCgEuvOinHOa5xrYk7vPumK1n721HpJ7W5aqHFt+8Ptv9HwMf7tA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

or get it from here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment.js